# How do I disable advanced fraud detection of stripe in react-stripe-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I finally found a way to disable stripe loading on every page of react website thus slowing down website and reducing website performance. I only need stripe on payment page and came across a solution to this, which is to disable the advanced fraud detection of stripe

https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention/advanced-fraud-detection#disabling-advanced-fraud-detection

with HTML it is done like this

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/?advancedFraudSignals=false"></script>
```

but am using the react-stripe-js with my react app

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js

Anyone know how I can apply the disable function also with `react-stripe-js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to [configure the stripe API](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) module before loading the React Components:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
loadStripe.setLoadParameters({advancedFraudSignals: false});

import { /*...*/ } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
```

Comment: ok just saw this https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#disabling-advanced-fraud-detection-signals `The loadStripe.setLoadParameters function is only available when importing loadStripe from @stripe/stripe-js/pure` so what do i do since i already have this line in my code??? `import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';`? do i have it added on another line or what?

Comment: ok solved by removing this line `import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';` and using this instead as instructed by docs `import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';`. thanks

Comment: tested and got rid of the annoying stripe on every webpage non-sense...much relieved now knowing i got stripe off my back..literally